# emacs dired reverse date order

Tags: emacs, dired

Is there a means to reverse the date sort order in dired?

Toggling to Dired by date mode by hitting 's' orders newest to oldest, top to bottom. I would like to reverse this so I see oldest to newest top to bottom

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Use a prefix argument to `dired-sort-toggle-or-edit`: `C-u s`. This lets you manually specify the flags you wish to pass to `ls`:

> Toggle sorting by date, and refresh the Dired buffer.
>   With a prefix argument, edit the current listing switches instead.

Then make sure to include both `-t` (to sort by modification time) and `-r` (to reverse the sort), e.g.

```
-altr RET
```

Answer (score 1):

You do not need to manually change the `ls` switches for Dired, even via `C-u s`.

Just use command `dired-sort-menu-toggle-reverse` from library [Dired Sort Menu](http://www.emacswiki.org/emacs/DiredSortMenu) ([`dired-sort-menu.el`](http://www.emacswiki.org/emacs/dired-sort-menu.el)).  `dired-sort-menu.el` binds it to **`r`** in Dired, by default.

If you also use library [`dired-sort-menu+.el`](http://www.emacswiki.org/emacs/download/dired-sort-menu%2b.el) and [Dired+](http://www.emacswiki.org/emacs/DiredPlus) then the command is rebound to **`|`** instead (`r` is for `diredp-rename-this file`).

Comment: do you mean type M-x dired-sort-menu-toggle-reverse? I don't seem to have that available (i'm using 24.3.1). Only similar thing that I have is dired-sort-toggle-or-edit

Comment: I mean (1) download [`dired-sort-menu.el`](http://www.emacswiki.org/emacs/dired-sort-menu.el), put it in your `load-path`, and `require` it. It binds `r` to `dired-sort-menu-toggle-reverse`. If you use Dired+ then you might want to bind it to a different key. If you also download library [`dired-sort-menu+.el`](http://www.emacswiki.org/emacs/download/dired-sort-menu%2b.el) then you get some enhancements to `dired-sort-menu.el`, and it automatically binds the command to `|` instead of `r`, since `r` is bound to something else by Dired+.